$H^2 (\mathbb{R}^3)$? (or in general $H^2 (\mathbb{R}^{2n+1})$)?
We know that $\mathbb{R}^2$ is an Abelian Lie algebra and $H^2 (\mathbb{R}^2)\cong \mathbb{R}$. We can define the three-dimensional Heisenberg algebra $\mathbb{R}^3=\mathbb{R}^2 \oplus \mathbb{R}$ where $\mathbb{R}^3=\langle Q,P,Z:[Q,P]=Z,[Q,Z]=0,[P,Z]=0\rangle$. This can be generalized to higher dimensions: by seeing $\mathbb{R}^{2n}$ as an Abelian Lie algebra. My question is that what is the second cohomology of $\mathbb{R}^3$ (on in general $\mathbb{R}^{2n+1}$)? I mean $H^2 (\mathbb{R}^3)$?

The Heisenberg Lie algebra is not a direct sum $\Bbb R^2\oplus \Bbb R$. It is a nonsplit extension of $\Bbb R^2$ by $\Bbb R$.

Santharoubane has proved in $1983$ in his article "Cohomology of Heisenberg Lie algebras" that
$$
\dim H^i(\mathfrak{h}_n(\Bbb R))=\binom{2n}{i}-\binom{2n}{i-2}
$$
for all $0\le i\le n$. For $i=2$ this gives $H^2(\mathfrak{h}_n(\Bbb R))\cong \Bbb R^{\binom{2n}{2}-1}$ for $n\ge 2$. Here we have $\dim (\mathfrak{h}_n(\Bbb R))=2n+1$.

Thank you very much for your help. Sorry, what does the notation $\mathfrak{h}_n(\mathbb{R})$ mean here? Heisengerg Lie algebra of $\mathbb{R}$?

Yes, the $(2n+1)$-dimensional Heisenberg Lie algebra, with basis ${x_1,\ldots ,x_n,y_1,\ldots y_n,z}$ and brackets $[x_i,y_i]=z$.

Understood. Appreciate you.
